# How to find a node from a file-like xml object in Python3?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

These is the content of a file-like object `toc`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<ncx xmlns="http://www.daisy.org/z3986/2005/ncx/" version="2005-1" xml:lang="eng">
    <head>
    ...
    </head>
    <docTitle>
        <text>THE_TEXT_I_WANT</text>
    </docTitle>

    ...
</ncx>
```

My Python3 codes now:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

# I get toc using open method in zipfile module
# toc : <zipfile.ZipExtFile name='toc.ncx' mode='r' compress_type=deflate>
toc_tree = ET.parse(toc)
for node in toc_tree.iter():
    print(node)
print(toc_tree.find('docTitle'))
```

The for loop can print out all nodes but `find` method returns `None`. `findall` method returns nothing either. Please anybody tell me why? Is there any better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there is a (default) namespace in your XML, searching for elements called `docTitle` will find nothing, as it is searching for un-namespaced elements called `docTitle`. Instead, you need to use clark notation with the full namespace URI:

```
toc_tree.find('{http://www.daisy.org/z3986/2005/ncx/}docTitle')
```

Comment: It works! Thanks. Can I use `namespace=` in `find` method?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.find

Comment: How come I replace 'docTitle' with 'text', `find` method returns nothing again??

Comment: because `find` and `findall` only search direct children by default. try using `find('.//{http://www.daisy.org/z3986/2005/ncx/}text')` as per https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#elementtree-xpath

Comment: Thank you for your answers!